# obtaining the css display value of an li element

Tags: javascript, css, html-lists

I'm attempting to find the css display value while iterating through an unordered list (), but for some reason FF doesn't display this value.  Here's what I have so far:

```
var LIs = document.getElementById('ulABC').getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i=0; i<LIs.length; i++) {
   alert('the li display value is :'+LIs[i].style.display+':');
}
```

All I get is a blank response.  Any thoughts?

Comment: as others have stated, this works only if you set it explicitly via the `style` attribute (see in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZsZ6N/)) <ul id="ulABC"> <li style="display:block">1</li> </ul>​ However, if you set it via a class rule, the style DOM attribute is correctly empty (see this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZsZ6N/1/))

Comment: That code will return the display attribute of the li element's inline style (if it has any). It won't give you the value for the attribute in the CSS rule that applies to that li however.

Comment: because the list is dynamic, the styling is set via class assignments.  It would be super convenient if the browser would just report the current css values whether set directly on the element or via style sheets, but I didn't build the browser (or the spec for that matter).  Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `LIs[i].style.display` mirrors exactly what is set in the `style` attribute. It does not reflect anything the browser got from stylesheets. To get these computed values, use [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle).

[This link](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/bede0123d99ed41ef2214edde795927e2a777f8a/src/css.js#L279) shows the jQuery implementation of their `.css()` property, which does exactly this. Note, that on IE below IE 9 you need to use a method named `document.documentElement.currentStyle()`, hence the `if..else` clause.

Comment: Nope, if you also want IE8 and below supported. Hence the link to the jQuery implementation. If you only support new browsers, then it's cross-browser safe.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tips Boldewyn!  I'll just use jQuery to be safe :)

Comment: Well, jQuery also only uses basic JavaScript. That's why I put the link to its source code in the answer. I suggest strongly to read the code instead of blindly following api.jquery.com. Especially if that's all you need, it's absolute overkill to load several dozens of kB only to utilize those 30-something lines of code. (Actually I'm quite fond of jQuery, but if you're a learner, you should start with the basics, and that is JS, not jQuery.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use getComputedStyle() if the display has not been explicitly set in-line or using javascript. It won't pick anything up from the stylesheet.